# 2.92 - weight painting

Tags: rigging

1. I've watched the tutorials and it deoesn't work in my case!
2. I've rigged the chap in weightpaint01. If I join the separate parts of him - the coat -the head - the boots etc. the texturing gets messed up. So I've left them separate.....
   (maybe I should join everything ans then texture using vertex nodes?)[image]
3. He needs weight painting - see Weightpaint02
4. But when I try this I only get one part going blue - there doesn't seem to be any way to get, i.e. both boots as they are interacting with each other.  WeightPaint03[image]

Maybe I'm on the wrong track here but would be grateful for any advice anyone has time to give
[image][image]

Comment: Images can be added with the image icon on the toolbar right above [your text](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/218880/edit)

Comment: Share your file: https://blend-exchange.com